# Remove unwanted array and reindex multidimetional array on PHP

Tags: php

my current array is like the first image, what my goal is to get it like the second image, which is more indexed rather than the first one, how to reindex the first image into something like the second image ? I already attach my code below. The reason that my index is not start from 0 is because the variable $i is always increment, and I don't know any other way than this, if you guys have other way, please teach me, I love to learn. Thanks!

```
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{          
    $data[$res['id_barang']][$i] = $res['id_rpph_detil'];
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

[image]

**1st image**

[image]

**2nd image**

Comment: Question is not clear , What is your desired output ?

Comment: `array_walk` and `array_values`?

Comment: @PeeHaa already try with array_values but the level 1 array is changing, not the 2nd level

Comment: That's why there is a `array_walk` in there

Comment: @PeeHaa so I need to create a function in order to use array_walk ?

Comment: No you do not. I would have helped you better. But there is no way for me to copy paste a working example from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Just push items to arrays using `[]`, like this:

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
    // Initialize the element, if it is the first item
    if (!isset($data[$res['id_barang']])) {
        $data[$res['id_barang']] = array ();
    }

    // Push
    $data[$res['id_barang']][] = $res['id_rpph_detil'];
}
```

Comment: this one is as close as my goal, but why there is an offset error : Notice: Undefined offset: 404 
Notice: Undefined offset: 595 
Notice: Undefined offset: 632 @erki A

Comment: @AlexYamin Fixed it by replacing is_array() with isset()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a counter variable, you don't need iterated fetching calls.

The result object (you should update your code to use `mysqli_` functions) is iterable and the columnar data is accessible as if an associative array.

```
$data = [];
foreach ($r as $row) {
    $data[$row['id_barang']][] = $row['id_rpph_detil'];
}
```

The empty brace syntax tells php to push the new element into the subarray with a new index / auto-incremented key.